# unicode to itrans in a text file in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: perl

I want 0 replacing '०' Unicode character. I am using a Perl script and trying the code given below.

```
my %table_digits =  
(  
 '०' => '0'  
 '१' => '1',  .....)
```

It's working fine with other Unicode characters. Those are being replaced by other numbers. But it is not able to replace '०' with 0. How it can be done?

Comment: It'd be helpful to post more of the relevant code, especially the part actually doing the replacement.

Comment: use strict;  

use utf8;  
use Encode;  
use Getopt::Long;  
use Pod::Usage;  my
  %table_digits =  
  (  '१' => '1',  
   '२' => '2',  
   '३' => '3',  
   '४' => '4',  
   '५' => '5',  ...)

Comment: You don't show any replacing...

Comment: Please provide the output of the `use Data::Dumper; local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($s, grep $table_digits{$_} eq '1', keys %table_digits));` (where `$s` is the string containing `०`).

Answer (score 3):

See [Unicode numeric value in Unicode::UCD](http://p3rl.org/Unicode%3a%3aUCD#num):

```
use 5.010;
use utf8;
use open ':std', ':utf8';
use Unicode::UCD qw(num);
for my $digit (qw( ० १ २ ३ ४ ५ ६ ७ ८ ९ )) {
    say "$digit==".num($digit);
}
```

Comment: `\p{Nd}` will match the characters for which `num` returns something useful. `\p{Nd}(?<=\p{Devanagari})` returns those of the Devanagari script.